# apache proxy server and rewritecond

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, proxy

Combination of a webserver and a tomcat server. Everything runs under https.

The tomcat server is only accessible via a proxy server.

I want to rewrite all requests with "my_module" to the tomcat server. (tomcatmodule.war)

proxy server: 10.10.10.10:8999
tomcat server : 11.11.11.11:8443

How do I setup my VirtualHost to use the proxy server to execute then my rewrite condition.

I tried folllwoing in my

```
    <VirtualHost *.443>
    RewriteEngine on

    ProxyRemote "*" "https://10.10.10.10:8999"

        RewriteRule ^/my_module/(.*)  https://11.11.11.11:8443/tomcatmodule/$1 [P,QSA,L]

ProxyPassReverse /my_module/  https://11.11.11.11:8443/tomcatmodule/
```

Trying to forwad the request like

example.com/my_module/api

and this should end up to call the tomcat like

https://11.11.11.11:8443/tomcatmodule/api

(through the proxy server)

[infrastructure overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhnTB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I did not activate:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```

one other super helpful tip is to raise the log level:

```
LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested but you could try this

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote * https://10.10.10.10:8999
ProxyPass /my_module https://11.11.11.11:8443/tomcatmodule/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath tomcatmodule/ /my_module
ProxyPreserveHost On
```